# System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart(); does load the application straight away?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a logic in the MainWindow() as the following. What happens is that after I upload the license file and the DXWindow is closed I call this

System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();
                        Application.Current.Shutdown(); and I notice it straight away start my application it does not check the logic in the MainWindow() anymore. How to force it to get back into the MainWindow() when I run the restart ?

```
public MainWindow()
        {
           bool licStatu = IsValidLicenseAvailable();

            if (licStatu == false)
            {
                if (licStatu == false)
                {

                    DXWindow1 l1 = new DXWindow1();
                    l1.ShowDialog();
                    if (l1.DialogResult.HasValue && !l1.DialogResult.Value)
                        Application.Current.Shutdown();
                    else {
                        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();
                        Application.Current.Shutdown();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {

                if (IsValidLicenseAvailable() == false)
                {

                    DXWindow1 l1 = new DXWindow1();
                    l1.ShowDialog();
                    if (l1.DialogResult.HasValue && !l1.DialogResult.Value)
                        Application.Current.Shutdown();

                }
                else {


                    if (crossDay == 0 )
                    {
                        // MessageBox.Show("al okCross day :" + crossDay);
                        InitializeComponent();
                     }  
              }

}
```

Comment: When the application restarts, it's going to call the form load.  There's no way that I'm aware of to force it to use another entry point.  Also, you call `Restart()` before the `Shutdown()`....that may be problematic as well (`Shutdown()` may not get called).

Comment: So what should I change to force it to go through the normal flow?

Comment: It is the exact equivalent of the user closing all of your windows and starting your app again from the desktop shortcut.  Very awkward when debugging, the app starts back up with the debugger attached.  The only odds you'll have "to get back into the MainWindow" is that your program does the usual thing when it start up, creating the main window.

Comment: @HansPassant yes what is your suggestion to this issue? I notice it just start away after the restart it does not get into the MainWindow() so my logic to lock it does not work any more?

Comment: My crystal ball says that "does not get into the MainWindow" actually means "my debugger isn't working".   You'd have to write Debugger.Break() in the code to have a shot at debugging it.  Really rather best to not rely on the Restart() crutch, you can verify a license *before* you create your main window.

Comment: How to verify before I create the main window? Actually that the function prototype so its the first function called I guess right.  I dont get you when you say write Debugger Break()?